# Tag synonym request for [tfs-api] and [tfs-sdk]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

These tags ([tfs-api](/questions/tagged/tfs-api) and [tfs-sdk](/questions/tagged/tfs-sdk)) are very similar and they should be synonyms of each other.

Excerpt from the [tfs-sdk](/questions/tagged/tfs-sdk) wiki:

> This tag is used to identify questions about the use of the TFS API, in any supported language, and any tools that support or build upon it.

There are currently 123 questions tagged [tfs-sdk](/questions/tagged/tfs-sdk) and 85 tagged [tfs-api](/questions/tagged/tfs-api).